# Python How to postprocess the data in a file which has data being written to it?

Tags: python, file, generator

I have data being written to different log files every hour. I am able to read the data in the log file line by line using:

```
import subprocess
f = subprocess.Popen(['tail','-F',filename],\
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    line = f.stdout.readline()
    data = line.decode("utf-8")
    #Steps to implement algorithm on data**
```

Then I am writing down the steps to postprocess every single line (=data) which is each line. The end of post process step happens only on the last line.

Comment: How do you know when you are at the "last line" ?

Comment: When I terminate the program I see the processed data information which is only the recent line written to the log file